# Why does running my circuit on Quantum Hardware produce such unexpected results?

Tags: programming, qiskit, ibm-q-experience, simulation, qasm

I am using Jupyter Notebook with Qiskit.

I have created a program that can add two 3-bit numbers together. When I simulate this program on a qasm_simulator it works as expected and I can add any two 3-bit numbers together such as:
$011 + 110 = 1000$

However, when I try to get the result on real quantum hardware (IBMQ) it gets very unexpected results as seen below.

[image]

I know there will obviously be noise when using the quantum hardware but the results aren't even close to what they should be, does anyone know why?

### My code:

```
%matplotlib inline
# Importing standard Qiskit libraries
from qiskit import QuantumRegister
from qiskit import ClassicalRegister
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, execute, Aer, IBMQ
from qiskit.compiler import transpile, assemble
from qiskit.tools.jupyter import *
from qiskit.visualization import *
from ibm_quantum_widgets import *
from qiskit.tools.monitor import job_monitor
from qiskit.providers.ibmq import least_busy

# Loading IBM Q account(s)
provider = IBMQ.load_account()

## Create COUT sub-routine

q0 = QuantumRegister(1) # First number
q1 = QuantumRegister(1) # Second number, then sum
q2 = QuantumRegister(1) # Carry bit i
q3 = QuantumRegister(1) # Carry bits i+1

# Build a COUT sub-circuit
COUT_qr = QuantumRegister(4)
COUT = QuantumCircuit(q0,q1,q2,q3,name='COUT')

COUT.ccx(q1[0],q2[0],q3[0])
COUT.cx(q1[0],q2[0])
COUT.ccx(q0[0],q2[0],q3[0])

# convert to a gate
COUT_inst = COUT.to_instruction()


## reverse COUT sub-routine

q0 = QuantumRegister(1) # First number
q1 = QuantumRegister(1) # Second number, then sum
q2 = QuantumRegister(1) # Carry bit i
q3 = QuantumRegister(1) # Carry bits i+1

# Build a COUT sub-circuit
reverseCOUT = QuantumCircuit(q0,q1,q2,q3,name='reverseCOUT')

reverseCOUT.ccx(q0[0],q2[0],q3[0])
reverseCOUT.cx(q1[0],q2[0])
reverseCOUT.ccx(q1[0],q2[0],q3[0])

# convert to a gate
reverseCOUT_inst = reverseCOUT.to_instruction()


## Create SUM sub-routine

q0 = QuantumRegister(1) # First number
q1 = QuantumRegister(1) # Second number, then sum
q2 = QuantumRegister(1) # Carry bit i


# Build a COUT sub-circuit
SUM = QuantumCircuit(q0,q1,q2,name='SUM')

SUM.cx(q0[0],q2[0])
SUM.cx(q1[0],q2[0])


# convert to a gate
SUM_inst = SUM.to_instruction()


# n is the length of the qubits you are adding together
n = 3

a = QuantumRegister(n,'a') # First number
b = QuantumRegister(n+1,'b') # Second number, then sum
c = QuantumRegister(n,'c') # Carry bits
cl = ClassicalRegister(n+1) # Classical output

# Combining all of them into one quantum circuit
qc = QuantumCircuit(a, b, c, cl)

# initialise numbers:
qc.x(0)
qc.x(1) 
#qc.x(2)
qc.x(3)
#qc.x(4) 
qc.x(5)


## Create the circuit to add two 3-bit numbers
# COUT
qc.append(COUT,[c[0],a[0],b[0],c[1]])
qc.barrier()

# COUT
qc.append(COUT,[c[1],a[1],b[1],c[2]])
qc.barrier()

# COUT
qc.append(COUT,[c[2],a[2],b[2],b[3]])
qc.barrier()


qc.cx(c[2],b[2])
qc.barrier()


# reverse COUT
qc.append(reverseCOUT,[c[1],a[1],b[1],c[2]])
qc.barrier()


# SUM
qc.append(SUM,[c[1],a[1],b[1]])
qc.barrier()

# reverse COUT
qc.append(reverseCOUT,[c[0],a[0],b[0],c[1]])
qc.barrier()

# SUM
qc.append(SUM,[c[0],a[0],b[0]])
qc.barrier()


# Measure qubits and store results in classical register cl
for i in range(3+1):
    qc.measure(b[i], cl[i])


# Run the experimient 1024 times and get stats
counts = execute(qc,Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')).result().get_counts()
plot_histogram(counts)

# Run on Quantum Hardware
provider = IBMQ.get_provider(hub='ibm-q')
backend = least_busy(provider.backends(filters=lambda x: x.configuration().n_qubits >= 10 
                                       and not x.configuration().simulator 
                                       and x.status().operational==True))
print("least busy backend: ", backend)

# Run it
shots = 2048
transpiled_qc = transpile(qc, backend, optimization_level=3)
qobj = assemble(transpiled_qc, shots=shots)
job = backend.run(qobj)
job_monitor(job)

# Plot results
counts = job.result().get_counts()
plot_histogram(counts)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I think you underestimated how long your circuit really is....

When running your circuit on the hardware, it has to be transpile into the set of gates that is known to the hardware. For IBM machines, these are $\{ CX, ID, RZ, SX, X \}$ . Furthermore, there is a constraint on the qubit layout of the hardware as well. Not all qubits are connected. Thus there will be some overhead operation. At the end of it, your circuit is very long... and so **all you read out is noise**...

[image]

Comment: Hahaha that's quite funny. @John it is of course possible to reduce the size of this by quite a lot. E.g. a 4 qubit increment can be done in 14 CNOTs ( https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/3975/119 ) instead of over 100, and adding is very similar to incrementing.

Comment: I also got the completely wrong results when I ran a 6-bit Quantum Phase Estimation. It sounds very exciting to have 15 qubits on the _ibmq_16_melbourne_. But, I think their stability is more important than anything else now. I wish I could read a white paper somewhere to understand what is the most meaningful circuit that the _ibmq_16_melbourne_ has ever accomplished so far.

Comment: Wow ok thank you so much for the explanation, makes sense!

Comment: @CraigGidney Thanks for the tip, i'll try that out

Comment: @KAJ226 Do you mind showing me how you decomposed my circuit into what you showed?